# How to implement pagination for folder contents in dropbox api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropbox-api

Is there any api call for implementing pagination for dropbox folders? Currently, I use `ListFolderAsync` to iterate over a folder’s contents where retrieving contents of large folders is very slow. `ListFolderGetLatestCursorResult` doe not return any result so I am not sure if this is the one.

```
var children = await GetClient().Files.ListFolderAsync(dbxItem.PathLower == DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH ? string.Empty : dbxItem.PathLower, limit:100); // limit controls the page size

while (children.HasMore)
{
     children = await GetClient().Files.ListFolderContinueAsync(children.Cursor);               
}
return children.Entries;
```

Comment: From a cursory read into this problem it looks like the API does not support pagination at all and unfortunately since it's a web request you can't really implement your own version of it without first fetching all of the data (which does not resolve your issue)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/issues/50) is their current stance on the issue (it's closed)

Comment: @RobertPetz Based on the link, it mentions `For ListFolder, you can't set a certain page size, nor is any particular page size guaranteed. You should just have your app call back to ListFolderContinue with the latest ListFolderResult.cursor if ListFolderResult.HasMore is true, and repeat until it is false`. Won't this paginate?

Comment: If you just need it to be able to chunk the data for performance reasons then yup just cursor through the data until you reach the end - but if you need to display pagination controls to the user then you won't know how many pages are involved and will be unable to build a standard pagination UI

Comment: @RobertPetz Ok, I am trying the above now. I don't understand the difference though so will try and see the results. But yes, I want it for persormance reasons. Currently, for folders >1000 files, dropbox files takes lot of time so I am finding a way to improve that. I am hoping this will help!

Comment: I gotcha - what I thought you meant by pagination was [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/img/pagination-sample.png) haha

Comment: @RobertPetz I was testing out some performance results. But there isn't any improvement. For 100 files, it took 33 s to load before and after changes. For files > 500, though, previously the folder failed to load but with changes its loading so that's a fix

Comment: unfortunately if you want to increase performance using a cursor like this you will need to make your front end asynchronous.  basically as you read through the data coming back from the server you will add it to your front end in real time instead of waiting for it to process all of the data.  since the API does not support proper pagination there isn't any way to speed up their side, but without seeing your code we can't go through and provide any performance tips to improve your side's performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API offers paging for listing files and folders via [`ListFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) and [`ListFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm). I.e., Dropbox will not return an unlimited number of entries per response. The [`ListFolderResult.HasMore`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderResult_HasMore.htm) in the response will indicate if you need to call back to get another page of results.

It does not offer the ability to request custom page sizes though.

Comment: @Robert Petz and @Greg So after changing the code and using `ListFolderContinue`, I am able to load the previously failed folder. However, its still slow. Is there any way to boost up the performance?

Comment: No, there isn't a faster way. Note that you can store and re-use the latest cursor though, to just get changes since you last called, so you don't need to go through every page each time.

Comment: I was testing out some performance results. But there isn't any improvement. For 100 files, it took 33 s to load before and after changes. For files > 500, though, previously the folder failed to load but with changes its loading so that's a fix.

Comment: You can now set an approximate limit on the [`ListFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) page size using the `limit` parameter

Comment: Thanks @Greg. What is the syntax to access limit. I updated the dropbox api to the latest 4.3.1 and still couldn't get the limit property. I am accessing as follows: `var children = GetDropboxClient().Files.ListFolderAsync(...);` and then `children.Limit` but no such property.

Comment: @Atihska `limit` is a parameter you should pass to [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) itself, not a property on the result.

Comment: Ohk, so does that mean I don't have to use `ListFolderContinueAsync` logic as  mentioned before or I should just add the parameter in `ListFolderAsync` and leave the `HasMore` logic as it is?

Comment: You should still do the `HasMore` logic. The `limit` just lets you control the size of each page.

Comment: Strange behavior seen with `limit`. I set the limit to 100 (as x) and have a folder with 106 (as y) items. I get to see just 6 (as z) items (latest items uploaded by date). Tested with different combinations of x and y and see this weirdness.

Comment: @Atihska Is that on `ListFolderContinueAsync` or `ListFolderAsync`? Is `HasMore` true?

Comment: Yes `HasMore` is true as when I don't use `limit`, I get the actual folder size which is 106 items in the above example. I have added my code in my question as an edit. Please check.

Comment: If `HasMore` is true, you need to call back to `ListFolderContinueAsync` to get the rest of the entries, no matter how many entries were returned. There are other factors on the backend that control how many items are returned per page, beyond the `limit` parameter, so it's possible that you'll see fewer in some cases.

Comment: Yes, I am calling back the `ListFolderContinueAsync` as in the code above. Just added `limit` param on `ListFolderAsync`.